# When did buggery come into common usage?

Tags: word-usage

When did the term buggery first evolve into common usage?

Comment: wikipedia...? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buggery

Comment: So you sign up with that name today and ask this question? Sounds like someone is taking the piss.

Answer (score 1):

The first reference that the OED has to the word ***bugger*** is from 1340, the first to ***buggery*** from 1533. The two expressions and the different senses of the word are connected.

> Etymology: < Anglo-Norman and Middle French bugre, bougre (French
>   bougre ) heretic (1172 in Old French as bogre ), person who performs
>   acts classed as ‘buggery’ (see buggery n. 2) (2nd half of the 13th
>   cent.), Bulgarian (early 14th cent.), general term of abuse or
>   contempt for a person (late 15th cent.) < post-classical Latin
>   Bulgarus Bulgarian (see Bulgar n.; also Bugarus , Bugaris , Bugerus ),
>   a name given to a sect of heretics thought to have come from Bulgaria
>   in the 11th cent. (probably ultimately referring to the Bogomils), and
>   afterwards extended to other heretics (to whom various deprecated
>   sexual practices were attributed) (13th cent. in British and
>   continental sources), and also to usurers (13th cent. in British
>   sources).   Compare Old Occitan bolgre and also ( < French) Middle
>   Dutch buggere heretic (early 14th cent.), person who performs acts
>   classed as ‘buggery’ (see buggery n. 2) (late 14th cent.; Dutch
>   bogger). In the Middle Ages, anal sex and various other sexual
>   practices which were deprecated (including bestiality, pederasty, and
>   incest) were attributed to members of various, especially dualist,
>   heresies, such as the Bogomils and the Albigenses (or Cathars). Such
>   charges were common during the period of the Albigensian Crusade
>   (1209–29), a military campaign initiated by Pope Innocent III to
>   eliminate Catharism from Languedoc, and appear to have been based on
>   Cathar avoidance of marriage and procreation on the grounds that they
>   led to a continuation of the physical world, which was held to be
>   intrinsically evil. Similar charges were associated with accusations
>   of heresy at other times, as for instance during the suppression of
>   the Knights Templars in the early 14th cent.

Oxford English Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**buggery** (n.) [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/buggery)

> mid-14c., "heresy," from Old French bougrerie, from bougre "heretic"
>   (see bugger (n.)). Later (1510s) "unnatural intercourse" with man or
>   beast, "carnalis copula contra Naturam, & hoc vel per confusionem
>   Specierum;" from bugger (n.) + -y

1st use as unnatural sexual intercourse: ~1500